# Como retornar um valor numa procedure do MySQL

Tags: mysql, procedure

Eu tenho a seguinte procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_CalculaVolume (
    IN vReservatorioCodigo bigint,
    OUT Retorno decimal
)
BEGIN
    Declare Formato int;
    Declare TipoReservatorio bigint;
    Declare retorno decimal;
    Declare vAltura decimal;
    DECLARE vDiametro decimal;
    Declare vRaio decimal;
    Declare vAresta1 decimal;
    Declare vAresta2 decimal;

    SELECT      @Formato := IFNULL(t.Formato, 0),
                @vAltura := d.Altura,
                @vAresta1 := d.Aresta1,
                @vAresta2 := d.Aresta2,
                @vDiametro := d.Diametro
    From        TipoReservatorio t 
    INNER JOIN  Reservatorio r ON (t.Codigo = r.TipoReservatorioCodigo)
    INNER JOIN  DimensaoReservatorio d ON (t.DimensaoReservatorioCodigo = d.Codigo)
    WHERE       r.Codigo = vReservatorioCodigo;

    IF Formato = 1 THEN
        SET vRaio = vDiametro / 2;
        SET retorno = 3.14 * (vRaio * vRaio) * vAltura;
    ELSE
        SET retorno = vAresta1 * vAresta2 * Altura;
    END 
END$$
Delimiter ;
```

Como pode ser visto, o parametro retorno esta definido como OUT e eu gostaria de ter esse parametro retornado ao chamar essa procedure. Porém não é isso que acontece.
Quando eu executo:

```
CALL sp_RetornaValor(1, @val); 
SELECT @val
```

Tenho o seguinte retorno:
[image: Retorno da procedure]

Como pode ser visto, não esta retornando o parâmetro OUT, mas sim o resultado do SELECT que tenho dentro da Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, acredito que está confusão está acontecendo pois você declarou o paremetro de saida "Retorno" com o "R" em maiúsculo,

```
OUT Retorno decimal
```

E depois está setando o valor a uma variavel "retorno" com o "r" em minúsculo,

```
SET retorno = 3.14 * (vRaio * vRaio) * vAltura;
SET retorno = vAresta1 * vAresta2 * Altura;
```

Acredito que se você alterar para "Retorno" irá resolver o problema.

```
SET Retorno = 3.14 * (vRaio * vRaio) * vAltura;
SET Retorno = vAresta1 * vAresta2 * Altura;
```

Espero ter ajudado ;)

Comment: Obrigado, Matheus.
Havia mais alguns detalhes à serem corrigidos mas sua resposta me ajudou.